# $\mathcal{Nil}_n$ isomorphic to $h^A$ with $A=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, functors

I would like to see that $\texttt{Nil}_n$ is isomorphic to $h^{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)}$ as categories.

$\texttt{Nil}_n: \texttt{Rings} \longrightarrow \texttt{Sets}$ is the functor that sends a ring $R$ to $\{x \in R | x^n = 0\}$.

$h^{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)}: \texttt{Mod}_R \longrightarrow \texttt{Mod}_R$ is the functor where $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)$ is an $R$-module and it sends an $R$-module $N$ to $Hom(\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n),N)$.

I know that two categories are isomorphic if when there exists two functors as above, they satisfy also the above conditions.

I want to see that if there exists two functors $F: \texttt{Nil}_n \longrightarrow h^{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)}$ and $G: h^{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)} \longrightarrow \texttt{Nil}_n$, then $FG=id_{h^{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)}}$ and $GF=id_{\texttt{Nil}_n}$.

But my problem comes when I have to find / see which are these functors. Does $F$ and $G$ even exist? How can I find them? Are they known functors?

I want to see that in order to see that $\texttt{Nil}_n$ is represented by the ring $h^{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)}$ and the natural equivalence

$\tau: h^{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)} \longrightarrow \texttt{Nil}_n$

given (for each ring $R$) by

$\tau_R: h^{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)}(R) \longrightarrow \texttt{Nil}_n(R): f ↦ f(\bar{x})$.

I was thinking on first showing that $\texttt{Nil}_n$ and $h^{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)}$ are isomorphic and then showing that there exists a natural iso $\mu: h^{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)} \longrightarrow \texttt{Nil}_n$ determined by $\mu_{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)}(Id_{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)})$ and it is equal to $\tau$.

Comment: You are asking for two functors to be isomorphic as categories, which doesn't make sense. They're not categories! Furthermore, you definitely don't want to consider $R$-module maps out of $Z[x]/x^n$ here-those have nothing to do with nilpotents. You should probably be showing that the representables associates to $Z[x]/x^n$ and $Nil_n$ are naturally isomorphic functors from rings to sets.

Comment: And how can I check if two functors are isomorphic?

Comment: You've already given the natural map $\tau$. Now you just need to show $\tau_R$ is an isomorphism for every $R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, several problems. As Kevin Carlson points out in the comments, $\newcommand\Nil{\operatorname{Nil}}\Nil_n$ and (if we define $A=\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)$) $h^A$ are functors, not categories.

Thus we need to show that they are isomorphic as functors.

**Isomorphisms of functors**

Recall, then, the definition of natural transformation, which is the notion of a morphism between functors. Let $F,G:C\to D$ be functors from a category $C$ to a category $D$. Then a natural transformation $\theta: F\to G$ is a family of maps, $\theta_x: F(x)\to G(x)$ for each $x\in C$ satisfying the following commutative diagram for every morphism $f:x\to y$ in $C$:
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}F(x) @>F(f)>> F(y) \\ @V\theta_xVV @V\theta_yVV\\G(x) @>>G(f)> G(y) \end{CD}$$

An *isomorphism* of functors (usually called a *natural isomorphism*) then is a natural transformation all of whose components are isomorphisms. (Check that this is equivalent to the natural transformation having an inverse natural transformation)

**How to apply this to your question**

First of all, you have the domains and codomains of your functors wrong. Well $\Nil_n$ is correct. It is a functor from $\newcommand\Ring{\mathbf{Ring}}\newcommand\Set{\mathbf{Set}}\Ring$ to $\Set$, but $h^A(R)=\newcommand\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom_\Ring(A,R)$ is actually also a functor from $\Ring$ to $\Set$, not from right $R$-modules to right $R$-modules.

Thus you want to find a family of maps for every ring $R\in\Ring$, $\tau_R:h^A(R)\to \Nil_n(R)$ with $\tau_R$ an isomorphism of sets (i.e. a bijection) for every ring $R$.
You should also check that $\tau_R$ is natural. I.e. that the following diagram commutes for every map $\phi :R\to S$ of rings:
$$\begin{CD}h^A(R) @>h^A(\phi)>> h^A(S) \\ @V\tau_RVV @V\tau_SVV\\\Nil_n(R) @>>\Nil_n(\phi)> \Nil_n(S) \end{CD}$$

**Note:** I've used $\tau_R$, because you've already identified the correct family of maps $\tau_R$ in your question, you just have to prove it has the right properties.

**Edit:** In response to your comment asking how is $\tau_R$ defined exactly.

Well, as you mentioned, the elements of $h^A(R)$ are ring homomorphisms $f:A\to R$, and the elements of $\Nil_n(R)$ are elements $r$ of $R$ with $r^n=0$. Thus $\tau_R$ should take ring homomorphisms $f:A\to R$ and produce appropriate elements of $R$.

Well, $A=\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)$, so let $\bar{x}$ be the image of $x\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ in the quotient, $A$. Then if $f:A\to R$ is a ring homomorphism, $r=f(\bar{x})$ is an element of $R$, and moreover, $r^n=f(\bar{x})^n=f(\bar{x}^n)=f(0)=0$, so $r$ is in $\Nil_n(R)$.

Comment: To the downvoter: I don't particularly care about the rep, but if you think there's something wrong with my answer, please leave a comment, and I'll try to address it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I do understand what you say. But I have a hard problem trying to understand what $\tau_R$ does. Because I know that elements in $h^A(R)$ are ring homomorphisms from $A=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)$ to $R$. And elements in $Nil_n(R)$ are elements in $R$ that are zero when we take the $n$-th power. But how can you map $f \mapsto f(\overline{x})$?I do not understand what that means. Any help?

Comment: @idriskameni edited.

Comment: Could you tell me if this would be correct to check commutativity? 
Let $h\in h^A(R)$. Then $(\tau_S \circ h^A(f))(h)=\tau_S(h^A(f)(h))=\tau_S(f\circ h)=( f\circ h)(\overline{x})$.
On the other hand, $(Nil_n(f) \circ \tau_R)(h)=Nil_n(f)(\tau_R(h))= Nil_n(f)(h(\overline{x}))= f(h(\overline{x}))=(f\circ h)(\overline{x})$. 
Hence, $\tau_S \circ h^A(f)=Nil_n(f) \circ \tau_R$.

Comment: To check bijectivity:
Injectivity: Given $f, g$ two different elements in $h^A$, it is clear that $f(\overline{x}) \neq g(\overline{x})$. Isn't it?
Surjectivity: Given $a\in Nil_n(R)$, we want to see that $\exists b \in h^{A}$ such that $\tau_R(b)=a$. (I am stuck here).

Comment: @idriskameni Sorry, didn't see these till now, commutativity looks good, I'll edit to address bijectivity later, since I've got to head out now.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057778/checking-the-functor-textttnil-n-is-represented-by-mathbbzx-xn) you can see my try checking bijectivity. You may can give me feedback there. Thank you very much! @jgon

Comment: @idriskameni Answered that question

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** there is a universal property of $\mathbb Z[x]$ as the free ring on one generator. This means there is a functorial identifcation $$Hom_{Rings}(\mathbb Z[x], R) = Hom_{Sets}(\{x\},R) = \{x\in R\} = R$$

Now describe this equality in terms of an isomorphism of functors and adapt the proof to your situation. (Yes the <s>functors</s> natural transformations exist and are well known.)